# How to break out of a running 'while' loop based on button press (Arduino)?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

So I am working on a Obstacle Avoiding Robot. So far everything is working fine except for this:

I have 2 modes. Idle and Obstacle Avoidance. Idle is basically blinking some LEDs and stopping any activity the robot might be performing. Mode switching happens on a press of a button. Here's the function that does that:

```
void manageRobotState() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == LOW) {
    robotState = 0;
    halt();
    idlePose();
    blinkLED(leftLED, 1000);
    blinkLED(rightLED, 1000);
  } else if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) {
    robotState = 1;
    digitalWrite(leftLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rightLED, HIGH);
    simpleObstacleAvoidence();
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

So the key here is that upon clicking the button the `robotState` variable gets changed. Now this code works, **EXCEPT FOR** the case when the robot is steering.

```
void smartTurnLeft() {
  turning();
  while (currentDistanceAhead <= minimumDistance) {
    Serial.println("turning");
    if (robotState == 0) {
      break;
    }
    scanAhead();
    leftMotor.setSpeed(50);
    rightMotor.setSpeed(50);
    leftMotor.run(BACKWARD);
    rightMotor.run(BACKWARD);
    blinkLED(leftLED, 20);
    digitalWrite(rightLED, LOW);
    delay(20);
  }
}
```

I have the feeling that when this loop is running nothing else can happen? I press the button however this while loop keeps executing. Is there anything that can be done?

The complete code can be seen [HERE](https://github.com/velchevski/Randy/blob/master/Randy.ino)

Comment: I don't see a method, only a function.And Arduino is not C.

Comment: I stand corrected, @Olaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about Arduino but assumed it was just like C.

And so I found [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Volatile) reference about the `volatile` keyword in Arduino.  It works just like C. The problem is that your test for `if (robotState == 0)` is being optimised out because the compiler can see that `robotState` isn't updated in the loop.

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that this memory address might be updated outside of normal program flow (either because it is a hardware register or because it might be updated via another thread of execution).  So the code change you need to make is to the declaration of `robotState`.  You might have similar problems with other variables.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction @dave, really helped me out here! Changing the `robotState` variable through a function called by an interrupt was the key to success! Interestingly enough it works even without declaring the `robotState` `int` as `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only thing you have to do is to call your `manageRobotState()` function inside the `while loop` in the `smartTurnLeft()` function, just like this

```
manageRobotState();
if (robotState == 0) {
   break;
}
```